# State not getting updated after editing in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, updates, reducers

Edit-This code is working fine now

I have been trying to update the paid property of an array of object called bill using the specific id.
the object that is getting passed to the action is not changing accordingly as well as the update is also not working in the reducer.
I am working on the editPaidStatus.
The object paid:this.state.paid gets passed till the action file correctly but after that there are no changes in the reducer so the state value for the specific bill id is not changing from false to true.The false was given to the paid property when the bill was made.Now I want that property to be changed to true[image: This value should get updated to true]

Here is my action file-

```
export const editPaidStatus = (id, updates = {}) => {
    console.log("running");
    console.log(id);
    console.log(updates);
    return {
        type: "EDIT_PAID_STATUS",
        id: id,
        updates: {
            paid: updates.paid
        }
    };
};
```

here is my reducer-

```
const billDefaultState = [];
const billReducer = (state = billDefaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_BILL": return [...state, action.bill];
        case "EDIT_PAID_STATUS": return state.map(bill => {
            if (bill.id === action.id) {
                return { ...bill, ...action.updates };
            } else {
                return bill;
            }
        });
```

here is the place from where the dispatch is being called-

```
<div>
    {this.state.payvisibility && (
        <MakePayment
          user={this.props.user}
          bill={this.props.bill}
          onMakingPayment={(billi = {}) => {
            this.props.dispatch(editPaidStatus(this.props.bill.id, billi));
            
          }}
        />
      )}
</div>
```

this goes to MakePayment.js file-

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import UserPaidBills from "../selectors/UserPaidBills";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { editPaidStatus } from "../actions/Bill";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class MakePayment extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onMakingPayment = this.onMakingPayment.bind(this);
        this.state = {paid: true};
    }

    onMakingPayment() {
        this.props.onMakingPayment({ paid: this.state.paid });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        console.log(this.props.user.FirstName);
        console.log(this.props.bill.billername);
        return (
           <div>
             <button onClick={() => this.onMakingPayment()}>Pay</button>
            <Link to={`username/${this.props.user.id}`}>Cancel</Link>
           </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect()(MakePayment));
```

Comment: are u getting udated object in `editPaidStatus ` action?

Comment: what are you using connect for in MakePayment if you don't have mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I am getting an object back at editPaidStatus but its value is fixed as true.And is not changing.i get an objetc{paid:true} at the action.as the local state is set to true.But any modification is not working

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I am passing user and bill as props from the third code snippet

Comment: @Striped billi is not a typo.Its just a temporary name that i have given to the object that we get into onMakingPayment from the MakePayment.js.

Comment: @Bhumika107 billi is not a typo.Its just a temporary name that i have given to the object that we get into onMakingPayment from the MakePayment.js which goes into the action as updates={}

Comment: @Striped Yes sorry that was a mistake I made while copying here.The code is ok.Till the actions everything is working.Its the reducer where the component is not getting updated.I have attached an image for reference

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN yes I want the value to be set as true in the fill update.It is set to false when I first added the bill.I have attached an image for reference.When I used the add bill action at that time I had set paid as false.Now I want that property only to be set as true